Example of non homogenous manifold with a finitely generated algebra of natural functions
Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold. Let $C^{\infty}_{Nat}(M,g)$ be the $\mathbb{R}$-algebra of scalar invariants of the curvature tensor and all its higher covariant derivatives. An example of a member of $C^{\infty}_{Nat}(M,g)$ is:
$$\sum_{i,j,b,k,c,d,f=1}^nR(e_i,e_j,e_j,e_k)\nabla R(e_k,e_b,e_b,e_c,e_i)\nabla R(e_c,e_d,e_d,e_f,e_f)-\sqrt{2} \sum_{i,j=1}^n R(e_i,e_j,e_j,e_i)$$
Question: If $C^{\infty}_{Nat}(M,g)$ is finitely generated as an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra, must $(M,g)$ be homogenous ? If not, can you please provide counterexamples ?
Thank you

No.  Here's a counterexample:  Let $f(r)$ satisfy the equation $f'' + 2 f^3 = 0$ with the initial conditions $f(0)=1$ and $f'(0)=0$.  Then $f$ satisfies $(f')^2+f^4=1$ and is periodic with period
$$
L = 2\int_{-1}^1 \frac{df}{\sqrt{1-f^4}} > 0.
$$
Moreover, $f(r)=f(-r)=-f\bigl(\tfrac12L-r\bigr)$ (so $f\bigl(\pm\tfrac14 L\bigr) = 0$) and $f'\bigl(\pm\tfrac14 L\bigr)=\mp1$.
Now consider the rotationally invariant metric $g = dr^2 + f(r)^2\,d\theta^2$.  This defines a smooth metric on the $2$-sphere (the poles are at $r= \pm\tfrac14 L$) with Gauss curvature $K = 2f^2$, which is not constant.  Hence, this metric is not homogeneous.
It is easy to see that $|\nabla K|^2 = 16 f^2(f')^2 = 16f^2(1-f^4)$,
which is a polynomial in $K$.  By induction, all of the 'natural invariants' of this metric are polynomials in $K$.  Thus, the ring of natural invariants of this metric is a polynomial ring generated by $K$, and hence, it is finitely generated.
(Even if one were to include $f'$ as a 'natural invariant', the ring of such invariants is still finitely generated as an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra.)
Added remark: In fact, there are lots of examples with no nontrivial symmetries.  It is not hard to show that if $M^2\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ is any smooth algebraic surface, the ring of scalar invariants (i.e., scalar contractions of $K,\nabla K,\nabla^2K,\ldots$) of the induced Riemannian metric is finitely generated.

Thanks Prof. Bryant for your help. It would be great if you can share the name of Weyl's paper where he proves that contractions of the curvature tensor and all of its higher covariant derivatives generate all the scalar polynomial invariants of the curvature tensor and its derivatives. I am also looking for a reference where a minimal set of generators in the 3 dimensional case is worked out. I tried searching google for sometime but wasnt succesful.Thank you

@Amr:  Presumably, what you want is the application of Weyl's theorem about scalar invariants of representations of the orthogonal group applied to the normalized power series expansion of metrics in normal coordinates.  See H. Weyl's "The Classical Groups" (the chapter on the orthogonal group) and P. Gilkey's discussion in Section 2.4 of his book "Invariance Theory, the Heat Equation, and the Atiyah-Singer Index Theorem".
